# Complexity restrictions for Google Maps kml

Tags: kml

What is meant by "Maximum number of total document-wide features = 1000"?
http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/mapsSupport.html

What is a feature in this regard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [KML Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html) page, that would probably be the maximum number of items that are derived from the `feature` class -- commonly `placemark` -- which act as containers for geometry and associated data.

So, assuming you don't hit the size limits, you could have up to 1000 point placemarks, or 1000 polygon placemarks, even if each polygon was made up of 1000 points.

Having said that, the page you reference defines a feature as "placemarks, polygons, lines", implying that you couldn't have a placemark that has a `multigeometry` object that itself contained more than 1000 geometries, but it would be fairly easy to generate a KML file that tests this. Additionally, it doesn't say what happens when the limits are reached: does it not render anything, or does it render as much as it can?

Comment: This is correct on a static (non-network kml) - Network KML with superoverlays are unlimited. But Google Maps API only supports static KML that go through Google Servers.

Comment: My kml file has about 3500 placemarks. I think I would notice if 1/3 of the markers were not showing. :)